# Azure mobile service Scheduler set to run a stored procedure fails to connect to DB

Tags: azure

In my Azure application I need to run a stored procedure periodically. I have created a mobile service in Azure and created a scheduler job which has script to run stored procedure.

```
function RunStoredProc() {
    console.log("Executing RunStoredProc...");
    mssql.query('EXEC dbo.StoredProcName', {
        success: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished executing RunStoredProc.");
        }
    });
}
```

I have also granted the execute permission on the stored procedure to the user that was created by mobile service.
When I run this job it fails with the following error message.

> Error Message:
>   Error occurred executing query: Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database  on server  requested by the login. Access to the database is only allowed using a security-enabled connection string.

Please provide any guidance on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give execute permissions to the user created by your scheduler. The user name will be something like `KeoecwqLOCLogin_RecurringAssignmentAlph`.

To give permission use the following command,

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO KeoecwqLOCLogin_RecurringAssignmentAlph
```

In case the user is missing, please create new mobile services as it will create the user when you bind the database with it.